# Shortcodes not working on archive intro on blog page

Tags: wordpress, blogs, genesis

I'm wondering if anyone knows why Genesis won't allow shortcodes to work on home.php or otherwise known as the 'blog' page? I'm trying to set up an excerpt on the blog 'landing page.' This is the page that is set as the ‘static’ Posts Page to show the blog separately from a WP home page under Settings > Reading.

I've been notified that the "content is not being passed through the Wordpress the_content filter that renders out shortcodes." Why is this?

I've tried this solution: https://joshuadnelson.com/code/allow-shortcodes-genesis-archive-intro-text/ and it does not change anything. I've set up a brand new Essence theme with no modifications except to show the archive intro, using  [this solution](https://www.billerickson.net/code/genesis-blog-archive-intro-text/) and of course, the codes to allow shortcodes. The only plugin activated is collapse-o-matic, since that is the main one I'm trying to get to work.

But no shortcodes work at all.

Comment: The blog landing uses `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you adding the shortcode exactly?

Have you tried `do_shortcode($myshortcodetag);`